# How to position few span's under each other

Tags: css, html

I want to position two span's and a button like so:

> span1
>
> span2
>
> button

But, with my current code they look like this:

> span1 span2 button

```
body {
text-align:center;
}
span#printHere {
color:black;
font-size:30px;
position:relative;
}
span#triesLeft{
align='centre';
font-size:30px;
position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try:

```
span {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
button {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
button:hover {
  background-image: url('imageurl');
}
```

clearing after a float will cause the span to drop to a new line.
http://jsfiddle.net/aKmF6/

Comment: I didn't know it. Thanks!

Answer (score 28):

`span` are inline elements.  If you want them positioned under each other use a block element or style it with `display:block`

http://jsfiddle.net/xfyS4/

Comment: You'll have to apply padding/spacing to the elements

Comment: @user2316675 - try adding padding-bottom:10px; for instance

Comment: okay thanks also i need it to be in middle of the screen under each other

Comment: Put them in a `div` with `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 4):

Can always go with flexbox,

```
<div style="display:flex; flex-direction:column">
  <span>Hello</span>
  <span>there,</span>
  <span>span!</span>
</div>
```